# I would like to determine a value $f(\alpha)$ according to two functions $f$ and $g$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Well it looks easy at first sight but I was not able to solve the underneath equation that  my son got during a math test.
$g(x)= x- e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$   , $g(x)$ has a zero at a value $\alpha$
so we have $\alpha e^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} =1$

Given  $f(x)= (x-2)(2e^{\frac{x}{2}}-1)$

**I have to demonstrate that if  $f(\alpha)= 4- \alpha - \frac{4}{\alpha}$    then  $f(\alpha)= -2.4$**

I started by replacing $e^{\frac{x}{2}}$ with $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ which gave me :
$f(\alpha)= 4- \alpha - \frac{4}{\alpha}$
( I know that's already given )

then I went throught all possible substutions to get rid of $\alpha$ in vain.

(Well I just gave my son the idea of the substituion and asked him to try to solve it alone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not quite true.

The real solution of the equation $\alpha \exp(-\alpha/2) = 1$ is $2 W(1/2)$ where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  I suspect that function is way over your son's mathematical level, so don't worry about it.  What it means at his level is that  you need to use numerical methods, not algebra, to solve for $\alpha$: if he has a graphing calculator it may be able to do it for him, and the answer is approximately $0.7034674224$.

With that value for $\alpha$, $4 - \alpha - 4/\alpha$ is approximately $-2.389587166$.

So maybe $-2.4$ is "close enough for government work".

Comment: Thanks for help. I am an electric engineer converted to Data Analytics and I don't remember we have such confusing questions during my Math Studies. 'll have a look at Lambert W function , just by curiosity.  Thanks /

Answer (score 1):

Function $x e^{\frac{x}{2}}-1$ is the derivative of $f(x)$. I'm not sure how is it supposed to help with finding the exact value of $f(\alpha)$ without knowing exactly what $\alpha$ is, but we can say that in $\alpha$ there is a local minimum of $f$. Probably the intention was to analyze the graph of $f$.

Edit: There was small typo in derivative.

Comment: yes the question figures within f graph analysis. I got $f'(x)=  e^{\frac{x}{2}}g(x)$ but that did not help me either. The Question is intented for High School (French baccalauréat ) final Term test